# How can I wake up the GTK thread from another thread (without polling)

Tags: multithreading, event-handling, gtk, gtkmm

One thread runs all things GTK (gtkmm actually), so essentially it runs 'Gtk::Application::run' which calls one of the 'main loop' functions of glib:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> refApp = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "com.alinoe.speech");
refApp->run(*new UIWindow(glade_path, css_path, "window1", jack_client));
```

Another thread handles Real Time audio and has no time to do anything that costs CPU time,
but sometimes needs to tell my GTK thread that it has to wake up and do something.

Of course I can have the audio thread set an atomic bit and have the GTK thread poll that bit, but I hate polling because it costs unnecessary CPU and/or introduces a delay between event and handling. Isn't there an official way to just trigger the GTK thread to "wake up" and call some user function?

Comment: The gtkmm tutorial has [a chapter](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-multi-threaded-programs.html.en) on this. I'm not familiar with gtkmm, but this strangely looks a lot more complicated than [the equivalent in the C API](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk3-Threads.description).